# What is the best way to add a list of 'skills' to a user model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

On my User's edit page I want users to be able to select from checkboxes what programming languages they know. I will give them about 15 to choose from. I then want to store these results in the User model to be accessed/searched for later.

What is the best way to go about this?

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply a many to many associations for achieving so. If you Google or even search SO, you will get lots of examples.

However, you can simply achieve same thing using the following gem

https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

It appears it's example matches your requirements. In the examples, they described same (skills) thing. So, you will get it done easily.